# Python: list index out of range when trying to compare two strings at index?

Tags: python, string

I have this function to check if a string contains three or more lowercase letters.

```
def lowerCaseValid(word):
lowCharList = ['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']
i = 0
flag = 0
while i <= len(word):
    j = 0
    while j <= len(lowCharList):
        if lowCharList[j] == word[i]:
            flag += 1
            j = 0
        else:
            j += 1
    i += 1
if flag >= 3:
    return True
```

In simple terms, I pass in a string (word) and create a list of acceptable characters (lowCharList).

Then, I set up a nested while loop that checks word[i] at every index of lowCharList, until it finds a match.

Then it resets lowCharList counter and adds 1 to flag, and moves on to word[i+1].

If it doesn't find a match by the time it reaches z, then it moves onto word[i+1] anyways.

For some reason, why I try my sample input in my main function.

```
def main():
  word = 'corRe!33'
  print(lowerCaseValid(word))
```

I get this error:

```
in lowerCaseValid
if lowCharList[j] == word[i]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why is it throwing this error? Thank you.

Comment: `lowCharList` is a list of one element.

Comment: How about `return len(i for i in word if i.islower()) >= 3`? (untested)

Comment: To your question why is it throwing the error, your while j loop goes for 1 too many items, as the string or list is zero indexed. Ie Len('abcde') = 5, but the last item is at index 4, so <= should be <.

Answer (score 1):

> using python's in operator is easier...

```
    def lowerCaseValid(word):
       cnt = 0
       lowCharList = ['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']
       chars = lowCharList.pop ()
       for ch in word:
           if ch in chars:
           cnt += 1

       return  cnt >= 3
```

> or with using sets just 2 lines of code

```
def lowerCaseValid(word):

    lowCharList = ['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']

    return len(set(lowCharList.pop()) & set(word)) >=3
```

> or one liner with map and lambda

```
def lowerCaseValid(word):

    return len(list(map(lambda x: x.islower, list(word)))) >=3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative approach using a list comprehension and string.ascii_lowercase instead of redefining the lowercase letters:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

def lowerCaseValid(word):
    return sum[x in ascii_lowercase for x in word] >= 3
```

How this works is that the list comprehension goes through each letter in word.  The `x in ascii_lowercase` will return a boolean value of either True (1) or False (0), then `sum` up the `True`s

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
lowCharList = ['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']
```

to

```
lowCharList = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

I believe this should help, since you have a list containing only 1 item, whereas this way, you create a list with 24 items (all different letters).

Answer (score 0):

As heemayl pointed out in the comments, `lowCharList` is 1 element long! Now you have 2 options: make lowCharList an actual list (`lowCharList = list ("abcd...")`), or keep `lowCharList` a string, which will work just fine (remove the brackets in the definition.

Might I suggest another method: checking if str.islower count adds up to >=3. So:

```
lower_count = 0
for letter in word: 
    if letter.islower(): lower_count += 1
if lower_count >= 3: return True
```

Also, as suggested in the comments:

```
return len ([letter for letter in word if letter.islower()]) >= 3
```

would work (better than my answer, which is just the expanded form of it)